# Getting wrong resolution on old samsung monitor

Tags: display, intel-graphics, monitor, samsung, display-resolution

Today i connected my pc with old samsung sync master 591s monitor and getting strange display resolution. My resolution is being set at 800x600 but still cant see my side panal. Well its look like vertical sides are much wider than actual monitor's physical size. Cant see left size panal and on right side cant see power button. I tried deleting monitors. Xml file in .configure folder. Tried to reset resolution from monitor's physical button but still same strange resolution everything is being cruved at both side of display. I dont have any graphics card installed on intel pc. Intel core i3 540 processer intel hd internal graphics. Ubuntu 15.10

Tried changing modes with xrandr still same cruvy disply. See my images

https://drive.google.com/folder/d/0B233u8HX9WFtbmFscDRuMThqZ2s/edit

Comment: did you use `cvt` to generate xrandr modes?

Comment: Yes.  I tried cvt 800x400 and xrandr--newmode.  But still my problem ws there only.  Sides of my window go band. Screen looks like inverse fisheye. Its look so weird.

Comment: The Samsung SyncMaster 591s looks like a very old monitor indeed, with actual CRT instead of LED. Have we tried this monitor with a different pc, or tried the pc with a different monitor? We want to rule out any hardware issues with the monitor itself. It would probably be a good idea to try a different VGA cable too. Once we have ruled out hardware, then let's do this just to be sure: type `lspci | grep VGA` and please edit your question and paste the output. Once we have confirmed you have an Intel graphics card, type `grep -i intel /var/log/Xorg.0.log` and paste the output.

Comment: Here are a couple of useful links: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Monitor_or_Screens https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the resolution manually via the Settings App under Display.